# java.lang.verifyError on hibernate specific usertype

Tags: hibernate

We have been using the [GenericEnumUserType](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/secure/attachment/11292/GenericEnumUserType.java) for our extensible enumerations and our classes fail to load in JBoss 6, on a Hibernate 3.6+ container.

The following error is thrown

```
#abc state=Create: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.type.Type
Factory.basic(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/type/Type;
```

on the following code

```
type = (NullableType)TypeFactory.basic(identifierType.getName());
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately @Enumerated does not work if you need to serialize based on something other than the Enum's ordinal or name.  I've managed to find a solution (modified slightly from [here](http://arylson.lowlevel.com.br/?p=135)).

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType;
import org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver;
import org.hibernate.usertype.ParameterizedType;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class GenericEnumUserType implements UserType, ParameterizedType {

    private Class<? extends Enum> enumClass;
    private Class<?> identifierType;
    private Method identifierMethod;
    private Method valueOfMethod;
    private static final String defaultIdentifierMethodName = "name";
    private static final String defaultValueOfMethodName = "valueOf";
    private AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType type;
    private int[] sqlTypes;

    @Override
    public void setParameterValues( Properties parameters )
    {
        String enumClassName = parameters.getProperty("enumClass");
        try
        {
            enumClass = Class.forName( enumClassName ).asSubclass( Enum.class );
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) {
            throw new HibernateException("Enum class not found", exception);
        }

        String identifierMethodName = parameters.getProperty( "identifierMethod", defaultIdentifierMethodName );

        try
        {
            identifierMethod = enumClass.getMethod( identifierMethodName,
                                                    new Class[0]);
            identifierType = identifierMethod.getReturnType();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new HibernateException("Failed to optain identifier method",
                    exception);
        }

        TypeResolver tr = new TypeResolver();
        type = (AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType)tr.basic( identifierType.getName() );
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new HibernateException( "Unsupported identifier type " + identifierType.getName() );
        }
        sqlTypes = new int[] { type.sqlType() };

        String valueOfMethodName = parameters.getProperty( "valueOfMethod",
                                                           defaultValueOfMethodName);

        try
        {
            valueOfMethod = enumClass.getMethod( valueOfMethodName,
                                                 new Class[] { identifierType } );
        }
        catch ( Exception exception )
        {
            throw new HibernateException( "Failed to optain valueOf method",
                                          exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass()
    {
        return enumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet( ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner )
        throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {
        Object identifier = type.get( rs, names[0] );
        try
        {
            return valueOfMethod.invoke( enumClass, new Object[] { identifier } );
        }
        catch ( Exception exception )
        {
            throw new HibernateException( "Exception while invoking valueOfMethod of enumeration class: ",
                                          exception);
        }
    }

    public void nullSafeSet( PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index )
        throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            Object identifier = value != null ? identifierMethod.invoke( value,
                                                                         new Object[0] ) : null;
            st.setObject( index, identifier );
        }
        catch ( Exception exception )
        {
            throw new HibernateException( "Exception while invoking identifierMethod of enumeration class: ",
                                          exception );

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes()
    {
        return sqlTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble( Serializable cached, Object owner )
        throws HibernateException
    {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy( Object value )
        throws HibernateException
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble( Object value )
        throws HibernateException
    {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object x, Object y )
        throws HibernateException
    {
        return x == y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode( Object x )
        throws HibernateException
    {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean isMutable()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public Object replace( Object original, Object target, Object owner )
        throws HibernateException
    {
        return original;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked till I migrated to latest version of hibernate. The `new TypeResolver()` is deprecated since 5.3 and I did not find any alternative for this yet.

Answer (score 2):

There's no TypeFactory.basic(String) in Hibernate 3.6 anymore. Compare the javadocs:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/TypeFactory.html
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/type/TypeFactory.html

I think it's now time to move from a custom UserType to the standard @Enumerated :-)

Comment: Unfortunately you can only use @Enumerated if you are serializing based on the Enum ordinal or name.  There are cases when this isn't appropriate.

Comment: I can confirm what mtpettyp is saying.  A common case for this is when you replaced 'magic numbers' with an enum, but you still have to keep the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the [TypeResolver](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/TypeResolver.java)'s code and took note of the inner implementation of the `basic` method, which is using classes not already deprecated. So, I replaced

```java
TypeResolver tr = new TypeResolver();
type = (AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType)tr.basic( identifierType.getName() );
```

with

```java
type = (AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<? extends Object>) new TypeConfiguration()
       .getBasicTypeRegistry().getRegisteredType(identifierType.getName());
```

And... So far, so good.