# Hibernate Enumeration Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enumeration

I have a legacy database table that, for simplicity sake looks like:

```
  table address{
    varchar line1
    varchar line2
    varchar line3
    varchar(1) deliveryline
  }
```

There is a check constraint on `deliveryline` guaranteeing it has the values `'1,'2', or '3'`.

This seems like a good candidate for enumeration in hibernate.  I have an entity that looks like this representing the Address table:

```
  public class Address{
    String line1;
    String line2;
    String line3;
    DeliveryLine deliveryLine;
  }
```

I normally use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` on when mapping enums, but that strategy does not work here.  For example:

public enum DeliveryLine {
 1,2,3
}
  This does not compile since the valid values in the database (1,2,3) are not valid Java Identifiers.

Is there a straightforward way to coerce this mapping in hibernate?

Comment: What database are you using? Can you change the data type of `deliveryline` in the database?

Comment: Oracle 10g/11g and unfortunately I am stuck with the given schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `GenericEnumUserType` described at [hibernate.org](https://www.hibernate.org/272.html) (Under "Flexible solution")

If you're using Hibernate 4 you'll have to use a modified version as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744179/java-lang-verifyerror-on-hibernate-specific-usertype/6231710#6231710)

Comment: I will be moving to Hibernate4 in the near future and it looks like I will be using your answer on the second link to make this work correctly.  In the meantime I mapped `delivery_line` column to a String property and linked the getter/setter property to the enumerated property I wanted.  Not exactly the cleanest solution but it works in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're locked into a varchar for column type, I think you're looking at a custom UserType.  Such as: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-ut